# Can force sensitivity be induced in non-force sensitive humans?

Tags: biology, super-powers

In the Star Wars Universe, Midi-chlorians are life forms that live symbiotically inside all living cells. Because of their properties, Midi-chlorians, when present in high enough quantities in an individual's cells, will cause Force-sensitivity.

On the same line of thought, shouldn't it be possible to induce force-sensitivity? An increase the Midi-chlorian counts in the body should be possible through organ or stem cell transplant from a Force-sensitive being. Even if Force-sensitivity is not tied to a specific organ, shouldn't such a procedure increase the total Midi-chlorian counts of the body as a whole, which should still result in force-sensitivity?

Comment: Hi and welcome!  This query asks about a third party SF/F world (SW Universe) and is thus off-topic here at Worldbuilding. Please delete your question and check out our sister group, [SciFi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: Also, no. Injecting Midi-chlorians has been tried in the EU, and the short of it is that it leads to horrible disasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to assume that midi-chlorians are the cause of Force sensitivity. The fact that they indicate Force abilities doesn't mean they cause them any more than white blood cell counts are the cause of disease. Also, midi-chlorians already exist within the cells of all living things in the Star Wars unierse, presumably as the equivalent of mitochondria. So even if it were possible, you'd also have to replace every cell inside a person for it to work.

The similar idea of genetic engineering Force sensitivity also doesn't seem possible because The Force can't possibly be a genetic trait. It is far too rare for this to be the case. Any organism with Force abilities would naturally have such a strong evolutionary advantage, comparable with eyesight on Earth, that the trait would inevitably spread widely. The fact that it has not done so indicates that it cannot be a genetic trait.

Comment: yes, that particular theory always struck me as mixing correlation & causation.  especially with several in-universe theories about belief and effort being all one needs (aka size matters not), which complicate the idea of what it means to be "strong" in the first place